# SIP relay for distributed calling

Tags: sip, asterisk

Here is my problem.  I do distributed calling with 10-15 Asterisk boxes.  They each have a different IP address.  My provider wants me to use IP based authentication, which can be a pain (the IP's change on a frequent basis).

I was thinking of setting up one Asterisk box to relay calls from all the others.  That way I'd just need to set up the SIP trunk to the provider on this one box/IP.

Can anyone tell me anything special I would need to do to set this up - either in the dial plan or otherwise?  I do not want all the media to run through the central box, I merely want it to set up the calls and allow the other boxes to talk directly to the provider once the call is set up.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a sip proxy like openser/kamailio or opensips would fit in best here. You could set the proxy up to relay all of the sip signalling to your cluster of asterisk boxes.

Here's [an example](http://kamailio.net/dokuwiki/doku.php/asterisk%3aload-balancing-and-ha) for doing this with Kamailio.

---

Also:

> I do not want all the media to run through the central box, I merely want it to set up the calls and allow the other boxes to talk directly to the provider once the call is set up.

Make sure that's groovy with your provider. A lot of ITSPs expect to signal and send media to pre-defined IP addresses. Generally they're talking to an SBC, which is expected to anchor the media and send it elsewhere..

Comment: Correct answer IMHO. If a provider won't support media and signalling coming from different IP addresses it's time to ditch them and get a real one!